# Salesforce 2 Salesforce changes made on target are not being updated on the source? Suggestions?

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I'm trying to set up a proof-of-concept for using Salesforce to Salesforce to permit access to a subsidiary's SF instance (Accounts, Contacts etc.) within my company's SF instance. I've set up sandboxes on both ends, configured the connections and sent and accepted the invite. I set up a simple exchange of some basic account fields which were sent to the target without any problems (once I figured out lookups). I should also note that the source is the subsidiary and the target is my company's instance.

Now, when I make a change on the target instance (my company's) the changes are not reflected back on the source instance. I was under the impression that changes flowed both ways and I believe I set everything up correctly. Can someone help a newbie out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you shared the objects from both the Source to the Target as well as the Target to the Source? You can set-up two way sharing with Salesforce to Salesforce (S2S) but to do so both orgs need to Publish and Subscribe to the objects and fields you want to have two way sharing.

A couple of caveats to keep in mind before implementing S2S. There are edge cases that can prevent S2S from working correctly. Take a look at the [known issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?tag=Salesforce%20to%20Salesforce). Based on my experience S2S is not a feature that is well supported by Salesforce. I have encountered problems that Salesforce Support "investigated" for well over a year before identifying the cause and then been told they likely won't fix the issue.

If I were building new functionality today I would not use S2S. Personally I would find some other method as the headaches and loss of data aren't worth it.

YMMV

Answer (score -1):

Once the record is forwarded any changes to the data later on will not get forwarded through connections

Comment: So it's just a one-way, one time sharing of information? Changes made on either end are not updated on the other?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: No this is incorrect. You can have two-way sharing but to do so you have to publish and subscribe from both orgs.